# Verifying 116725 = 116 * 725 or not? C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Question: input an int number ex: ABCD, verify that is ABCD = AB*CD or not

(note that we don't how many digits this number got, just know it is an positive integer

and yes, it the number of digits is odd we can conclude result is No, immediately by... eye lol)

for example:

```
    Enter a number: 88
    Output: No

    Enter a number: 12600
    Output: No

    Enter a number: 116725
    Output: Yes, 116 * 725 = 116725 (**this is just example, 

not actual result, just help to understand how output look like**)
```

Problem is that, you **can't** use **array**, **[jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Jump_statements)** and **bitwise** in order to solve this. Yes, if we can use array then not much to say, put input number in an array, check first half multiply other half....bla..bla... I need help with **IDEA** without using array to solve this problem, right now I'm stuck! Thank you guy very much!

Comment: That last example doesn't work!

Comment: 116725 is not the the same as 161725!

Comment: oh, sorry, I mean this was just example

Comment: But it doesn't actually work either :) 116 * 725 = 84100, 161 * 725 = 116725! Of course it doesn't affect potential solutions, just didn't want you to be relying on that for a test case or you'll be wondering what's wrong with your code all night!

Comment: How are you supposed to handle numbers with odd-number digits like 12600? Try both 12 * 600 and 126 * 00, ignore them completely or something completely different?

Comment: What is meant by you can't use **jump**? No **jump** == no **if** and no **for**, **while**? Since these do jump in the generated assembly...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Jump_statements

Comment: Just a warning: when the teacher tells you "you can't use feature x to solve this problem" is usually an indication of that the programming course is a bad one. Vote to close still "you can't use..." is a requirement that will not help any future readers of this post.

Comment: -1 on the above comment. No doubt the teacher has also said, "you can't use Java" (or would if asked). Restrictions on the tools/techniques you can use do not "usually" indicate a bad course, they indicate a course that's about the tools and techniques you can use. In this case, I think the lesson is that you can manipulate digits in base 10 using arithmetic operations. Permitting students to not learn the lesson at hand, just because they've thought of some other way to do it, isn't *universally* a good idea.

Comment: But quite aside from that, this assignment is ridiculous for other reasons (see Joni's answer).

Comment: And why is there C/C++ in the title? That always makes me itch.

Comment: I know it not important as IDEA but "C/C++" indicates that will use exact these language to write a program, in some cases, that makes helper much easier to help and less confusion for asker. (ex: compare 2 string value can use == in C/C++ but not in java, just an example)

Comment: LOL the joke is that it's obviously impossible for AB*CD to ever equal ABCD

Comment: LOL, my opinion is that nothing ridiculous or funny joke there, both question and answers could be right or not quite right or even wrong, who cares? question can given some thing that is wrong and ask you to prove that, what you mean by "wrong question"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little hint to your 6 digits number:

- to get last 3 digits use `% 1000`
- to get first 3 digits use `(int) X/1000`.

Notice that `1000 == 10^3`.

Comment: And if it isn't always six digits you can multiply or divide by 10 until you get the correct number of digits.

Comment: You can determine number of digits using logarithm: `(int)floor(log((double)n) / log(10.0) + 1.0);`

Comment: Don't see how this is the accepted answer. It's more of a comment

Comment: @keyser5053 I don't see why you don't see this as the good answer... Author looking for way to split big number into 2 pieces, and here it is... haters gonna hate?

Comment: @ProblemFactory I'll grant you that it's above comment-grade, but no, I wouldn't interpret his question like that. No hate :)

Comment: +1. this is the correct answer because OP wants help with the **IDEA** ~any more than this would be *doing* the homework, duh

Comment: di `tits` sounds a bit wrong ;), otherwise a good answer :) +1

Comment: @NiftyDude well... funny typo :] Thx!

Comment: guys, what if we can permutate the digits in each half, that means 161 * 725 = 116725 should be output YES (because 161 or 116 both are permutation of {1,1,6}, so you have any idea to solve that? Mine is use 4 link lists, 1-2 to store digits of each half and 3-4 to store permutation of them, then N divide each node of linked list 3 compare that result to every node of list 4

Comment: Ask new question on SO, permutation is much more complex problem... :)

Answer (score 16):

Your program can safely output `No` for every input. Proof:

You are looking for integers A and B such that A*B = A*10^k + B, with A and B > 0 and B < 10^k.

If A*B = A*10^k + B, then B = 10^k + B/A > 10^k. But B had to be less than 10^k, so this is a contradiction. Therefore no such A and B exist.

---

A longer proof:

You are looking for integers A and B such that A*B = A*10^k + B, with A and B > 0 and B < 10^k.

Subtract B from both sides to get (A-1)*B = A*10^k.

Since A is a factor in the right hand side it is also a factor in the left hand side. But A and A-1 are coprime, so A must divide B. So, B = n*A for some integer n.

Now we have A*B = A*10^k + n*A, or A*B = (10^k + n)*A. Since A > 0 we can divide both sides by A to get B = 10^k+n. But this is impossible since B was supposed to be less than 10^k!

Comment: +1. A shorter proof: you're looking for `A` and `B` positive integers such that `A * 10^k + B == A * B`, with `10^k > B`. This is impossible since `A * 10^k + B > A * 10^k > A * B`.

Comment: @JoniSalonen However, since you omitted the word "positive", look out for inputs like `00`.

Comment: @MrLister: It's traditional when mathematicians do these puzzles, to say that all numbers must be written in their canonical form, no leading zeroes (unless the number is exactly `0`). Hence `A != 0`, and the rest follows. But you're right, this question doesn't bother specifying the input format, so maybe `00` should be considered a pass, and for that matter maybe so should `0x0000` (with `A == 0x0` and `B == 000`).

Comment: Well spotted, I'm getting rusty.. Going to update with a proof based on a similar argument. @MrLister by "A and B > 0" I mean both A > 0 and B > 0, maybe I should have spelled it out..

Comment: [Computer says No](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOdjCb4LwQY)

Answer (score 6):

Write a program that asks for the input and then prints "No".

Done.

Comment: hah :) not very constructive, but I like your attitude

Comment: It's true though. See Joni's answer for proof.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too clear what you're trying to do.  ABCD == AB*CD suggests
four digit numbers.  For a four digit number `x`, a test for the above
would be `x == (x / 100) * (x % 100)`.  For a six digit number, replace
`100` with `1000`, and more generally, for an `n` digit number, where
`n` is even, use `10^(n/2)`.  If `n` is odd, however, I'm not sure what you're looking for, and the last example you give doesn't meet the criteria you mention; if you can permutate the digits in each half, the problem then becomes more complex.

Comment: "for a `n` digit number, where `n` is **odd**..." Did you mean "even"?

Comment: no permutation of digits in each half there

Comment: Hey James, if we can permutate the digits in each half, so you have any idea to solve that? Mine is use 4 link lists, 1-2 to store digits of each half and 3-4 to store permutation of them, then N divide each node of linked list 3 compare that result to every node of list 4

Comment: @LongBodie In such a case, I'd use an array of the digits, for each side, and `std::next_permutation`.  (I know that the original question said no arrays, but I suspect that any other solution will be significantly more complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

You can read a string, split it in the middle and convert the both parts to an int.

You could also read an int, calculate the number of digits (writing your own loop or using the log function) and split the int after the calculated number of digits.

You can also write a loop that is taking an int ABCD, splitting it into ABC and D and moving the digits from ABC to D while the both have not the same number of digits (you do not need to calculate the number of digits here, there is a quite easy comparison you can do).

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of digits, count how many times you had to divide the number by 10 until it gets smaller than 1.

For 116725, you would need to divide by 10 six times. After that you can print no if the number is odd or calculate the result like James Kanze and ProblemFactory described.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete "C/C++" solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
    return puts("No.");
}
```

Comment: @[LongBodie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1320817/longbodie) ~i like to imagine you handing this in as your completed assignment; & to imagine the gritted-teeth smile the teacher flashes you when it gets handed back. heh.